# AngularJS and Sanitize - Sanitize HTML without ngBind Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-sanitizing

Lets supose we need to sanitize an HTML string and we can't use ng-bind-html directive, for example:

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit {{customer.name}}">Text</span>
```

If we have special chars in customer.name this line would be printed as the html version like `&eacute;` and we want `é` instead.

I have tested with:

- `$sce.trustAsHtml(customer.name)`
- `$sce.parseAsHtml(customer.name)`

But nothing can "translate" this html. How can be this done?

A short explanation would be: how to sanitize html inside a directive (not in the body with `ng-bind-html`).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be so complicated.

Instead, use `setAttribute` and `textContent` (V.S. innerHTML) on elements, and browsers themselves will take care of sanitizing for you.

```
// To set element attributes
$span.setAttribute("title", "Edit" + customer.name);

// To set element content
$span.textContent = customer.name;
```

For more details, see [the post here](http://luxiyalu.com/angular-sanitize/). These are one time bindings of course, so if you need updates, just throw `$watch` in the midst.

Comment: Yes, it could b e solution, no so elegant or angular way solution. It could generate a lot of source code in the controller depending on the amount of sanizitations you have to do, even so many functions for modularity minded to the scope and watches. this is my only solution, I suppose I have to accept it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From an [oficial documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce):

> ngBindHtml uses $sce.parseAsHtml(binding expression). Here's the actual code (slightly simplified):

```
var ngBindHtmlDirective = ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return function(scope, element, attr) {
    scope.$watch($sce.parseAsHtml(attr.ngBindHtml), function(value) {
      element.html(value || '');
    });
  };
}];
```

so I think all you need is `$sce.parseAsHtml` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#parseAsHtml).

---

If you are not able to persuade angular to print HTML anyway, you can try to use

```
customer.name.replace(/&eacute;/g, String.fromCharCode(233));
```

You can find some basic codes here: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/accentedcharacters.htm

That should work, but it is not definitely the best solution. You should always use `ng-bind-html`.

Comment: Yeah, I know that solution, replacing wil work always. But my question is about using ngSanitize plugin in order to do the sanitization of every html char (even unsafe) outside the `ng-bind-html`, I mean where u cannot use the directive like the example I showed. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: I did try that solution before askin. I did a function `return $sce.parseAsHtml(value)` but it didnt works, and in the HTML `title="Edit {{parseCode(customer.name)}}"`.